# Как в background-blur-plugin вставить картинку через img, а не background?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Подскажите как вставить картинку тегом img, а не background в [этом](https://github.com/msurguy/background-blur) плагине.
Background не подходит, т.к. буду добавлять php переменные для динамической замены картинки. Заранее спасибо!

Моя структура HTML

```
<div class="new__item" id="new-item">
   <img src="img/news-img-1.png" alt="">
   <div class="img-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.new__item {
  width: 33.3%;
  max-width: 540px;
  max-height: 870px;
  height: 87vh;
  color: #fff;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  .img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("../img/overlay-img.png");
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 103%;
    min-height: 870px;
    height: 87vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
}
```

JS

`$('#new-item').backgroundBlur({
    imageURL : 'http://URL-of-the-image',
    blurAmount : 50,
    imageClass : 'bg-blur'
});`

Добавил свой код и JS background-blur-plugin. Возможно так будет нагляднее.

Comment: надо создать блок обёртку (я пример не смотрел) внутри два блока , в первом находится картинка во втором блоке абсолютно расположен `blur()`если что то не ясно скажите я приведу пример

Comment: примерно так https://jsfiddle.net/ztyjp4a6/10/